# How do we window join using SQL client in Flink SQL query?

Tags: streaming, apache-flink, flink-streaming, windowing, flink-sql

How do we window join using SQL client in Flink SQL query. 
Windowing in the same fashion as mention in link below
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/dev/stream/operators/joining.html

Sample Query that requires windowing
SELECT sourceKafka.* FROM sourceKafka INNER JOIN badips ON sourceKafka.`source.ip`=badips.ip

sourceKafka is source-table, with continuous stream of kafka
badips is another source-table

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a time windowed join, using Flink SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders o, Shipments s
WHERE o.id = s.orderId AND
  o.ordertime BETWEEN s.shiptime - INTERVAL '4' HOUR AND s.shiptime
```

See the [docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/dev/table/sql.html#joins) for more details.

Comment: Then, How to write tumbling/sliding/session window join using Flink SQL? see https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/joining.html